# How do selectively position overlapping points on y axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I was wondering how to make my categorical variables appear in a certain order in the plot? Right now the green dot at y =YZ is on (1,1) but the green dot at y =YZ is more like (1,2.2). I would like it on (1,YZ) exactly.

How can I specify the exact coordinates of my points?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
 x<- c("1","1","1","1","1")

    y <- c("XY","XY","XY","YZ","YZ")

    z <- c("Treatment 1","Treatment 2","Treatment 3","Treatment 1","Treatment 2")

    data<- data.frame (x,y,z)

    ggplot(data=data,aes (x=y, y=x, color = z)) + 
    coord_flip() +
    geom_point(pch = 16, size = 3, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
    xlab("ID") +
    ylab("Time") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I think the main way to do this is to add another row for the "YZ" group that has `NA` for `z`. so you have the same number of observations for each group.  Like `data = rbind(data, c("1", "YZ", NA) )`. You will also need to add `scale_color_discrete(na.translate = FALSE)` so the `NA` value is dropped from the discrete color scale.